# PhpStorm with remote development not getting focus on breakpoint when debugging

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, remote-debugging

I'm doing development on our remote server. In PhpStorm I set up the SSH connection, it installed the headless PhpStorm on the remote server and opened the JetBrains Client. Everything is working fine, but I have some problem with debugging via Xdebug.

I set up all the ports, "Can accept external connections", set a breakpoint in `index.php`. When I go to the browser it keeps loading and is apparently working, because when I manually change focus to my JetBrains Client, the flow really stops on the breakpoint. I can see the variables, step over, etc. However, I'd expect that the IDE gets the focus automatically.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Since you say your debugger is actually working fine and your only problem is that the IDE window does not steal focus, you should probably include details about your setup. At the very least, what operating system are you using.

Comment: The host remote is running Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS and I'm using macOS Ventura 13.4. I'm not the one who set up XDebug on the remote server and am in contact with the DevOps guy, but it's hard to reach him. Therefore I'm trying my luck here. I googled a lot of information and tried various settings both in php.ini and PhpStorm, but am not really an expert in the server administration

Comment: I don't believe anything is wrong here. PhpStorm doesn't steal focus for me either, and never has — unless it prompts with a "can't find this path" error due to path mappings missing. In any case, nothing is wrong on the Xdebug side, as as you say, the debugging works and Xdebug can't focus apps on your computer.

Comment: I can't [reproduce this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sch51D7SBYM7htifKNaFOoISyLDBbjek/) in a similar environment. Do you have focus on breakpoint enabled at all at *Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger*? Also, what PhpStorm version are you using on the remote side?

Comment: @Derick maybe that's the answer. Maybe there's nothing wrong. I was just curious, because when I was trying this with Magento running in a Docker container on my local environment, PhpStorm stole the focus.

Comment: @EugeneMorozov yes, I have this setting on. I'm using 2023.2 Beta JetBrains Client. What's the Debug bookmark in your browser?

Comment: @Peter It doesn't matter; it just a thing that adds the debug cookie so that Xdebug started upon the HTTP request.